# IE 8 not displaying page

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-8

My page is not displaying in IE8. It works fine if I debug in IE and change it to IE7 standards under Internet Explorer 8 browser mode. I'm not sure what is wrong. If I add a meta tag with IE7 specified, it loads the page, and then looks like it forwards it to a blank page. All of the html is there in the debug information, and it works fine in IE7 browser mode, or in Firefox. Any ideas? Here is my header:

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site2.master.cs" Inherits="Site2" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Header" Src="~/Controls/Header.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Footer" Src="~/Controls/Footer.ascx" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/Jquery.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/menu.js") %>" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("Scripts/EasyConfirm.js") %>" type="text/javascript" > </script>
    <link href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("Styles/jquerySmoothness.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

     </head>
<body  >

    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data" method ="post" >

      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled" EnablePartialRendering="true"    runat="server" />


    <div class="container">
        <uc:Header runat="server" ID="headerTest" Title="RTSC SCM" Subtitle="Logistics SOS" />



  <div class="content2 " style ="position:relative; padding-bottom: 10px"   >


  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"/>


      <%--</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>--%>

    <!-- end .content --></div>
       <uc:Footer runat="server" ID="footer" TeamName="RTSC Logistics SOS Tool Support Team" />


    <!-- end .container --></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="RTSC SOS - Storage Request View" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StorageRequest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Forms_StorageRequest" ContentType="IE7" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="EmployeeSearch" Src="~/Controls/TinyEmployeeSearch.ascx" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/AdditionalInfo.ascx" TagPrefix="R" TagName="AddInfo" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/LamEditComments.ascx" TagPrefix="R" TagName="StorageLocation" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/RequestHeader.ascx" TagPrefix="R" TagName="reqheader" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/HandlingUnitInfo.ascx" TagPrefix="R" TagName="handlingView" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/DocumentGrid.ascx" TagPrefix="R" TagName="docView" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/EmailGrid.ascx" TagPrefix="R" TagName="emailView" %>
<%@ Register src="~/Controls/RequestInfo.ascx" tagname="requestinfo" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
<script type ="text/javascript" src="../Forms/FormsJS/StorageRequest.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>

<div id="input" runat ="server" style="width: 960px" >
    <R:reqheader id="m_reqHeaderCtr" runat="server" />
    <r:docView ID="docView" runat="server" Visible = "true" />
    <r:emailView ID="emailView" runat="server" Visible = "true"/>
    <uc1:requestinfo ID="requestinfo1" runat="server" Visible = "false" />
    <%-- Request Edit Information --%>
    <fieldset id="RequestEdit" runat ="server" style="border-color: #CCC; width: 960px;" > 
        <legend style="border-style: none;font-size:small; color: Blue;">Request Information</legend>
        <div  style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float:left"  >
        <table>
            <tr style="height: 25px;">
                <td  class ="BDecoNone bold" width="60px">
                    <img id="star1" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/> Program: 
                </td>

                <td width="120px">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="strgProg_DD" Height="20px" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="TBDecoSmall">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <span id="Program_Span" runat="server" />
                </td>

                <td runat="server" id="Other_TR" class="bold" style="text-align:right;display:none;"> 
                    <img id="star3" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars" />
                    <asp:Label ID="OtherTD" Text = "Other Program:" Width = "73px"  runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>

                <td width="100px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="m_otherProgramTB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDecoNone"  ViewStateMode="Enabled"  Height="12px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td width="100px">
                &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td class="bold TBDecoSmall " >
                    <img  id="star4" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/>Ownership:
                </td>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <span id="m_ownershipSpan" runat="server" class="bold" />
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="OwnRadioButtonList" runat="server" CssClass="bold" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>

                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold TBDecoQuan"  style ="width:150px">
                    <img id="star5" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/>Check to Certify:
                </td>

                <td colspan="1">
                    <span ID="Material_CB_Span" runat="server"></span>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Material_CB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="cb bold" Text="Material is NOT Classified" Width="150px" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="bold TBDecoSmall" style="width: 150px; height: 24px;">
                    <img id="star6" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/>Storage Requirements:
                </td>

                <td colspan="1" style="height: 24px">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="m_storageList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="Space bold" RepeatColumns="5" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
            <tr ID="TempStorageInstruction_TR" runat="server" >
                <td class="bold TBDecoSmall" colspan="1" style="width: 180px">
                    <img  id="star7" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/>Temperature Storage Instructions:
                </td>

                <td >
                    <span ID="TempStorageSpan" runat="server" class="bold"></span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TempStorageInstruction_TB" runat="server" CssClass="Bmar TBDecoLong" ValidationGroup="saveAll" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Height="20px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr ID="OtherStorageInstruction_TR" runat="server" >
                <td class="bold TBDecoSmall" style="width: 150px">
                    <img  id="star8" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/> Other Storage Instructions:
                </td>

                <td >
                    <span ID="m_otherInstSpan" runat="server" class="bold"></span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="OtherStorageInstruction_TB" runat="server" CssClass="Bmar TBDecoLong" Height="20px" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine"  ValidationGroup="saveAll"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div  style="position: relative; width: 360px; float: right; height: auto; padding-top: 5px; top: 0px;"  >
        <div  class="TBDecoNone" style ="padding: 0x; margin: 0px; float: left"  >
            <img id="star2" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/> Program Point of Contact:&nbsp;
        </div> 

        <div style ="float : left"> 
            <uc:employeesearch  id="progrmPointOfContact_TB" runat="server" scheme="Red" Enabled="false"  /> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    </fieldset>  



    <fieldset runat="server"  id ="EditGrid" style="border-color: #CCC; width: 960px;">
            <legend style="border-style: none;font-size:small; color: Blue;">
            Handling Unit Information</legend>
            <div id="GridHolder">
                <R:handlingView ID="handlingViewGrid" runat="server" Visible = "true" />
            <br />
            </div>
        <div> 
            <input type="button" id="m_addNewItem" value="Add Material" style="border-color:#87BF83;color:Black" class="AddB" onclick="AddMaterial()" />
        </div>


<div id="m_detailsView" runat="server" style="display:none">
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"> 
        <tr>
            <td class="TextDeco"><img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Material Number:</td>
            <td class="TextDeco"><img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Description: </td>
            <td class="TextDeco"> &nbsp;&nbsp; Manufacturer:</td> 
            <td class="TextDeco"> &nbsp;&nbsp; Model:</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- End Header section-->
        <tr style="height: 20px; vertical-align: top;">
            <!--Material TextBox ID=MatNum_TB-->
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="MatNum_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="175px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
                <br /> 
            </td>
            <!--Description TextBox-->      
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Des_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="175px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <!--Manufacturer TextBox-->       
            <td class="TBDeco">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Manufac_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="250px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
            </td>

            <!--Model TextBox-->
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Model_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Wrap="False" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="TextDeco">
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Material Type:
            </td>
            <td class="TextDeco" style ="width:150px">
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" class="RedStars" alt="red_star"/>Inv. Classification:
            </td> 
            <td class="TextDeco" >
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Shelf-Life:
            </td>
            <td class="TextDeco" >

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td> 
            <!--Material Type DropDownList-->                        
                <asp:DropDownList ID="MatType_DD"  Height="20px" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="150px" ></asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
            </td>

            <!--Inventory DropDownList-->   
            <td>                    
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Inv_DD"  Height="20px" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="150px"></asp:DropDownList> 
                <br />
            </td>

            <td width="240px">  
            <div style="float: left; height: 20px auto; width: 130px;" >
                <asp:TextBox ID="SLife_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDecoSmall" Wrap="False" Width="120px" onclick="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_SLife_TB').focus();"></asp:TextBox> 
                <br />
            </div>

            <div style="float:right; height: 20px auto;"   >
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Unlimit_CB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="TBDecoSmall" Height="20px"  Text="Unlimited" />
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--Header--> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="TextDeco">
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Charge Number:
            </td>
            <td class="TextDeco" style="margin-left:15px;">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Owning Cost Center:
            </td>
            <td class="TextDeco" style="margin-left:15px;">
                &nbsp;&nbsp; Unit Value:
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="bold" style="vertical-align: top">
            <!--Charge Number TextBox-->          
            <td width="250px">               
                <asp:TextBox ID="Charge_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="143px"></asp:TextBox> 
                <br />
            </td>

            <!--Owning Cost Center TextBox-->
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Own_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="143px"></asp:TextBox> 
                <br /> 
            </td>

            <td>                        
                <asp:TextBox ID="Line_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDeco" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" rules="none" frame="void" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
        <tr class="bold ">
            <td width="108px">
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars" />Serialized: 
            </td>
            <td width="60px" >                         
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Seri_RB" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false" Width="80px" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList> 
            </td>

            <td width="193px">
                <img id="starForQuantity" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/> Quantity:
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="Quan_TB" runat="server"  Width="143px" Wrap="False" CssClass="TBDecoNone"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <td width="300px" id="SerialNumber" runat ="server" >
                <img id="starForSerial" runat ="server" src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="Red Star" class="RedStars"/> Serial Number:  
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="Seri_TB" runat="server" Width="120px" CssClass="TBDecoNone" Wrap ="false" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>       
        </tr>   
        <tr class="bold " >
            <td>
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Moisture Sensitive:  
            </td>

            <td width="60px">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Moist_RB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="bold "  >
            <td >
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star"   class="RedStars"/>Hazardous: 
            </td>

            <td width="80px">                        
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Haz_RB" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="false" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr class="bold" runat="server" id="MSDS_TR" style="display:none">
            <td width="130px;">
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>
                <asp:Label ID="MSDSLabel" runat="server" Text="MSDS Number:"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td width="100px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="MSDS_TB" runat="server" CssClass="TBDecoSmall" Wrap="False" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <td></td>

            <td width="440px" colspan="1" > 
                <div style="float:left" > Attached MSDS: </div>  
                    <input type="file" id="MSDSFileUpload"  runat="server" style="width:330px;height:20px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="pkg" runat ="server" >
        <tr class="bold"  >
            <%-- Pack_TR is to make the red star image visible/invisible--%>
            <td  runat="server" id="Pack_TR" visible="true" >
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Packaging Requirement:
            </td>

            <td colspan="3" style="width: 468px; text-align:left;" align="left">                        
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="PackingReq_CBL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
                CssClass="Space"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Visible="true" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id ="pkgOther" runat ="server" style="display:none">
        <tr id="OtherPkgRequirent_TR" runat="server" class="bold " style ="vertical-align:middle;"  > 
            <td>
                <img src="../Images/red_star.gif" alt="red_star" class="RedStars"/>Other Packaging Requirement:
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="OtherPkgRequirent_TB" runat="server" Width="550px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>  

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <center>
        <div id="mat_err" style="color:red" runat="server" ></div>
        <div style="">
            <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save Material Number"  onclick="return SaveMaterialData();" /> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <input type="button" id="btnSaveAddMaterial" value="Save and Add Material Number" /> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel"  onclick="Cancel()" /> 
        </div>
    </center>                  
    </div> 
    </fieldset>

</div>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net?  Or is this just html?

Comment: Thnx.  I retagged to include that fact.  Details such as that are important.  Having said that...are you aware if any code in the code-behind that might be checking for browser version and possibly redirecting?  Also, consider kolin's answer - it's likely this is a markup issue failing and thus affecting the whole page.

Comment: If I had to take a stab in the dark (and I wouldn't have to if you linked full code), then I would guess there's a `document.write` somewhere. Or maybe a `javascript:` pseudo-protocol.

Comment: No, there's no document.write, or javascript: pseudo-protocol. Like I said, it works fine in IE7 and firefox. It also was working fine just a few days ago. I'll post the code in just a minute.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say run the generated HTML through the validator that [kolin linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11294987/363815)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running it through the XHTML validator?
http://validator.w3.org/

you may find errors in there that are compromising the rest of the page's html.

Comment: Good thought, but not really an answer.